# Submit button alert box bug. How do I identify the bug and fix the code?

Tags: javascript, html

HELP! I need to know for this code to pop up an alert box, but the submit button does not bring it up! What is the bug and how can I fix the code without entirely changing the all of it? Thanks!

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>

 <html>
 <head>

 <title>Dougie's Script</title>
 <script>
    var textinput;


    function submitHandler(e){
        alert("You entered " + textinput.value + "\n");
        e.preventDefault();
    }

    textinput=document.getElementById("textfield");
    var form = document.getElementById("theform");

    form.addEventListener("submit", submitHandler, false);

 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <form id="theform" action="#">
    <label>Enter text here...</label>
    <input id="textfield" type="text" >
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" >
 </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: You're getting the element, but the element isn't rendered/ready yet...

Answer (score 0):

Move this to underneath the ending form tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
textinput=document.getElementById("textfield");
var form = document.getElementById("theform");

form.addEventListener("submit", submitHandler, false);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Move your `<script>` tag to the bottom of your `<body>`:

```
    </form>
    <script>...</script>
</body>
```

Right now, your script is trying to look for elements that haven't been created yet. The alternative would be to listen for the `document`'s `DOMContentLoaded` event, but that isn't cross-browser.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving your script tag to the very bottom of the body. This way the script will execute after the document has loaded (and then your elements should be "gettable" and "listener-attachable".)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the elements of the page have yet to load when the javascript is ran. Therefore, `document.getElementById("textfield")` does not return an element, and no event is tied to it.

Try encapsulating the event handling of your javascript code as follows:

```
var textfield;
function submitHandler(e) { ... }

// When the window loads, run this function.
window.onload = function() {
    textfield = document.getElementById("textfield");
    var form = document.getElementById("theform");

    form.addEventListener("submit", submitHandler, false);
 }
```

That will make sure the event is tied to the element once it is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Remember to keep things in scope; where you are grabbing the text input dynamically every time you call the function in-order to keep the value updating within the response. Also, make sure the DOM is loaded before trying to access elements within the HTML tree, and since you are using `addEventListener`, here is a working version of your script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Dougie's Script</title>
        <script>
            (function(d){
                var init = function(){
                    var form = d.getElementById("theform"), submitHandler = function(e){
                        var  textinput = d.getElementById("textfield");
                        alert("You entered " + textinput.value + "\n");
                        e.preventDefault();
                    };
                    form.addEventListener("submit", submitHandler, false);
                };
                d.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init, false);
            })(document);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="theform" action="#">
            <label for="textfield">Enter text here...</label>
            <input id="textfield" type="text" >
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" >
        </form>
    </body>
 </html>
```